# how to implement voip in existing application

Tags: voip, voip-android, windows-phone-voip

I have a project where i have to implement voice call feature in an open source texting android application (BRIAR).
i have the source code and all app files downloaded and opened on android studio but don't know what to do exactly or where to start to reach destined goal ,unfortunately i have no prior experience in android development, the app is uses java .
i have tried multiple sites and procedures but non seem to be working or too complicated to understand

if any one knows where to start or knows how to add the required feature please tell me.